# Datatables AJAX Get Fields from joined Table

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTables and AJAX.  I am having difficulty getting fields from the secondary table that are connected through the primary key.  The only thing that I am able to show is the primary key. In this case concern_id.

Model: Question

```
    public int question_id { get; set; }
    public int concern_id { get; set; }
    public string question_text { get; set; }
    public string question_answer { get; set; }
```

Model: Concern

```
    public int concern_id { get; set; }
    public string concern_desc { get; set; }
```

I would like to be able to show the concern_desc. If I don't use AJAX in datatables I can easily grab the field I need.

Example:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.concern.concern_desc)
```

Controller:

```
   public JsonResult GetQuestionRecord()
    {
        bool proxyCreation = db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
        try
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var list = (from q in db.questions
                        join c in db.concerns on q.concern_id equals c.concern_id
                        select q).ToList();

            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreation;
        }

    }
```

View:

```
<table id="DataTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ConcernID</th>
        <th>QuestionText</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetQuestionRecord();
});

var GetQuestionRecord = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetQuestionRecord","questions")',
        success: function (response) {
            BindDataTable(response);
        }
    });
}     
var BindDataTable = function (response) {
    $("#DataTable").DataTable({
        "aaData": response,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "concern_id" },
            { "mData": "question_text" },
        ]
    });
}
```

What do I change in the "mData : concern_id" to in order to display  "concern_desc" . I tried:

```
{ "mData": "concern_desc" }
```

And

```
{ "mData": "concern.concern_desc" }
```

Comment: Return an anonymous object containing the properties you want - `select new { concern_desc = c.concern_desc, question_text = q.question_text }` and then in the script `{ "mData": "concern_desc" }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks that was very easy fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Change your LINQ query in the Controller to this.

```js
        var list = (from q in db.questions
                        join c in db.concerns on q.concern_id equals c.concern_id
                        select new
                        {
                            question_id = q.question_id,
                            concern_id = q.concern_id,
                            question_text = q.question_text,
                            question_answer = q.question_aswer,
                            concern_desc = c.concern_desc
                        }).ToList();
```

Step 2: Change your BindDataTable JS code to.

```js
var BindDataTable = function (response) {
    $("#DataTable").DataTable({
        "aaData": response,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "concern_id" },
            { "mData": "question_text" },
            { "mData": "concern_desc" }
        ]
    });
```